# User Roles import scenario

Tags: acumatica

I am having an issue trying to Use Acumatica Import Scenario for uploading User Roles Access By Screen to Acumatica. I am using Import Scenario from Tim Rodman's website https://www.timrodman.com/sample-acumatica-import-scenario-access-rights/
The issue is that I provide a full path to a particular screen, but by some reason this import scenario affects only those screens that are not reports!

I.e. I am populating 2 paths in Import scenario to have **Delete** access for both for my Custom User Role:

1. Company/Finance/Accounts Payable/Reports/Audit/AP Edit
2. Company/Finance/Accounts Payable/Configuration/Setup/Accounts Payable Preferences

So the result will be that 1st path will not be affected by import scenario.
I am not sure, probably for those screens that are reports I have to have another parameter in Import Scenario? The best for me would be to use Acumatica Screen ID for Import, but unfortunately I don't know if that's possible.

Please advice if someone has ideas. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I fairly got a minus for my post because I was setting the same Access Rights = 'DELETE' to Reports, but they require another Access Rights word = 'GRANTED' :)

Very stupid mistake, but I am happy I figured that out without spending too much time on that. Probably will be helpful for someone